# PHP: Issue decoding JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm attempting to decode a JSON array, however I get the following error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

The JSON Encoded array is shown below:

```
echo json_decode('{
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [
      {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
         149.23531999999997,
         -35.352484
        ]
       },
       "properties": {
        "Fcilty_typ": "MO",
        "gx_id": "1"
       }
      }
     ]
    }'
);
```

I've stripped some fields out of this to keep it more compact for this query. Could anyone suggest what the issue is here?

Thanks

Comment: answer is already in question.. json_decode will return object no a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON,

The `{` character denotes the start of an object.

The `[` character denotes the start of an array.

So when you do a `json_decode()` it takes a string and makes out of it whatever the json structure denotes. Therefore in your case it creates an PHP Object of type `stdClass` with properties etc

You cannot `echo` an object, but you can use these functions on both Arrays and Objects

```
print_r() a nice simple display of the data

var_dump() a more complex to read display of the data in my opinion
           but it does show data types and sizes

var_export() similiar to print_r()
```

You can also add a second paameter to the `json_decode($string, true)` and it will convert objects found in the json string representaion of the data structure to Arrays, although I have never seen the need for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't echo the JSON you decoded (which is an object), you can however try a `var_dump`:

```
var_dump(json_decode('{
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [
      {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
         149.23531999999997,
         -35.352484
        ]
       },
       "properties": {
        "Fcilty_typ": "MO",
        "gx_id": "1"
       }
      }
     ]
    }'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `echo` a class, and the `echo` just print string.

Try change the `echo` for `var_dump`.

`var_dump` will show you the classes properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are decoding JSON data and echoing it out. Dont forget that echoing only works for strings, the JSON decode returns an other object.